# How to integrate Tinymce with Symfony encore?

Tags: symfony, tinymce, yarnpkg, webpack-encore

I have a **Symfony4** project using **flex** and **encore**. I would like to add tinymce.

So I add tinymce project:

```
$ yarn add tinymce
```

I edited my `app.js` file:

```
require('../css/app.scss');

// Import TinyMCE
import tinymce from 'tinymce/tinymce';

// A theme is also required
import 'tinymce/themes/modern/theme';

// Any plugins you want to use has to be imported
import 'tinymce/plugins/paste';
import 'tinymce/plugins/link';

// Initialize the app
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',

    plugins: ['paste', 'link']
});
```

I compiled:

```
$ yarn run encore dev
```

Compilation is successfull:

```
Running webpack ...

 DONE  Compiled successfully in 17600ms                                                                                                                                                                                                             

 I  8 files written to public\build
Done in 20.23s.
```

My textareas are replaced by a blank page.

I found the solution in [documentation](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/usage-with-module-loaders/#gettingtheskin) and it works fine when I copy the `node_modules/tinymce/skins` directory to `/public/build/skins`. But I still have to do it after each yarn compilation

**Is there a way to automatically copy this `node_modules/tinymce/skins` directory to `/public/build/skins`?** IS it possible to update the `webpack.config.js` to do it?

PS: I read some [recommandations](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/usage-with-module-loaders/#webpackfile-loader) with the `webpack-loader`, but I don't understand what I have to do.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**OPTION1: RECOMMENDED: the buit-in `copyFiles` function**

Use Encore's built-in `copyFiles` function.

```js
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

//...

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')

    // copy tinymce's skin files
    .copyFiles({
        from: 'node_modules/tinymce/skins',
        to: 'skins/[path]/[name].[ext]'
    })
```

[Encore's API reference](https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/blob/80555b9b43221f9195553f3c246cc6318403c25b/index.js#L589).

**OPTION2 : The copy webpack plugin**

I added the [copy webpack plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin)

```
yarn add copy-webpack-plugin --dev
```

I edited my webpack.config.js to only add 4 lines:

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

//DECLARATION OF THE NEW PLUGIN
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

Encore
// the project directory where all compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')

    // the public path used by the web server to access the previous directory
    .setPublicPath('/build')

    // will create public/build/admin/app.js and public/build/admin/app.css
    .addEntry('admin', './assets/js/app.js')

    //Some project lines
    //...
    //...
    
    //I call the plugin with its new syntax (since 3.11)
    .addPlugin(new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
            // Copy the skins from tinymce to the build/skins directory
            { from: 'node_modules/tinymce/skins', to: 'skins' },
        ],
    }))

    //Some project lines
    //...
    //...
;

// export the final configuration
module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for your post... It solved my issue with a slight difference for me. I had to put the skins in

```
/public/build/js/skins
```

So I changed hte webpack config from

```
.addPlugin(new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    // Copy the skins from tinymce to the build/skins directory
    { from: 'node_modules/tinymce/skins', to: 'skins' },
]))
```

to

```
.addPlugin(new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    // Copy the skins from tinymce to the build/skins directory
    { from: 'node_modules/tinymce/skins', to: 'js/skins' },
]))
```

And it works ! thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

Note that since v3.11 of the copy plugin, the syntax changed and previous answers won't work anymore. The new syntax requires the *patterns* field:

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

// Plugins
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

...

Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')  
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')

    .addPlugin(new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
            // Copy the skins from tinymce to the build/skins directory
            { from: 'node_modules/tinymce/skins', to: 'skins' },
        ],
    }))

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the third party plugin `copy-webpack-plugin` I'd recommend using Encore's built-in `copyFiles` function.

```js
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

//...

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')

    // copy tinymce's skin files
    .copyFiles({
        from: 'node_modules/tinymce/skins',
        to: 'skins/[path]/[name].[ext]'
    })
```

See Encore's [API reference](https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/blob/80555b9b43221f9195553f3c246cc6318403c25b/index.js#L589).